# Atomic Chess - Pawns

Tags: lichess, atomic-chess

I have been playing atomic chess on [lichess](https://lichess.org/) for some time but I still can't definitively state what pawns captures will look like. I think they have a kill radius of 1 but it doesn't effect other pawns? If anyone has a clear and decisive answer, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The captures in atomic chess work as follows:

1. The captured and capturing piece always die.
2. Then, anything around the capture square that's not a pawn dies.

For en passant, the capture square is the "bypassed" square of the double pawn move.

See https://lichess.org/variant/atomic or https://illion-atomic.netlify.app/atomic-rules/